# Difference Matte Keying software

Tags: video, software, effects, composing, freeware

I would like to know if anyone out there knows of any free software, or software not as expensive as Adobe After Effects, that can do [Difference Matte Keying](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103a9d3c597-7b52a.html#WS3878526689cb91655866c1103a9d3c597-7b4ba)? I have searched the web a little and have not come up with any promising results. **Note: Chroma Keying is not an option. I am on a Windows 7 computer.**

Thank you in advance for your time, and possible help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Blender](http://blender.org), which is **free and open-source**, can do difference matte keying.

I don't know if it's better or worse than After Effects' keyer because I haven't used it before.

[image: Difference matte keying with Blender's node-based compositor.]

Comment: Thanks. I've used Blender alot, but never thought about that. Your's is my favorite answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [Cinelerra can](http://cinelerra.org/docs/split_manual_en/cinelerra_cv_manual_en_14.html#Difference-key). Haven't checked how well it works though, I've been wanting to install it for quite some time but never got around to doing it yet.

Comment: You don't have to _convert_ your computer, it's no problem to install a Linux parallel to Windows (assuming that's what you're using now). Do it, it's worth the effort! — Cinelerra might even run under Windows with Cygwin, though getting that to work tends to be rather difficult. — I don't mind if you don't accept this answer, but you should add something about the operating system to the question body, especially since you write "[free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)" there, which at least to me suggests a _preference_ for Linux.

Comment: Ah, sorry about not mentioning the OS. I am on windows (7). And the converting my computer was somewhat of a joke. :D

Answer (score 0):

Check the blend modes of your video tracks. Almost any actual editing and compositing software, has blend modes for "Difference". So i'm nearly sure, you don't need a separate software.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the same thing. Difference blending just combines two images, while difference matte uses one image to create a mask for another one through which it can then be combined with a third image.

Comment: Sure, but create your difference-blend node (assuming a node-based compositor), feed it into a keyer, and there you are, a difference keyer.